# Not able see the image after uploading on admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning django but i am stuck at Imagefield. I am trying to rename the file and save the image to my media directory where exactly i am going wrong i am not able to understand. It was working fine till worked with filefield. after changing the filefield to imagefield i am getting an page not found.

```
Not Found: /media/products/926045120/926045120.jpg
```

above is the error

```
from django.db import models
import random
import os

def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext


def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    # print(instance)
    #print(filename)
    new_filename = random.randint(1,3910209312)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "products/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format(
            new_filename=new_filename, 
            final_filename=final_filename
            )

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

model.py of product

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'z45+z23#cgk-fem6x&6i9_n@tz8p3)f^l+f1#8$e^n7(hv&dgz'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "media_root")
```

products/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

# Create your views here.
from .models import Product


class ProductListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/list.html"

    # def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #   context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    #   print(context)
    #   return context


def product_list_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
    'object_list': queryset
    }
    return render(request, "products/list.html", context)




class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print(context)
        #context['abc'] = 123
        return context


def product_detail_view(request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):

    #instance = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    instance = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    context = {
    'object': instance
    }
    return render(request, "products/detail.html", context)
```

details.html

```
{{ object.title }}<br/>
{{ object.description }}<br/>

<img src="{{ object.image.url }}" class="img-fluid"/>
```

I am able see my images in media directory but it is not able view on page

Comment: Where is the code that you're using to execute the image retrieval? Also, what server are you running? Do you have a web proxy in front for static assets?

Comment: I am see the images if i remove the upload_image_path and use products/ in image field upload